# Media Foundation Sink Writer error E_NOINTERFACE (0x80004002)

Tags: c++, com, video-capture, ms-media-foundation, windows-10-desktop

The goal is: record a video (no audio) stream from a webcam **as-is**, i.e. no transcoding.

Current implementation is to use a simple topology like the following (node numbers in parenthesis for reference when reading the trace log):

```
[Source (0)] -> [Tee (1)] -> (auto-added Decoder (2)) -> [EVR (3)]
                          \-> [Sink Writer (4)]
```

Using the `IMFMediaSession` to handle the topology resolution (after having had bound the *EVR* output by resolving the *Activation* object as described in [MSDN - binding outputs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb250383(v=vs.85).aspx))

If I do not add the *Sink Writer* at all - the session works just fine, producing an output (video preview) in the specified window. Works regardless of whether there's a *Tee* node present or not (as expected).

The problem arises when I'm trying to incorporate the *Sink Writer* into the *Topology*.

*Sink Writer*'s initialization is quite minimalistic. Basically only the `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL()` providing the name of the output file and `IMFAttributes` specifying the *no converters* with *no hardware transforms* plus a *low latency* and *no throttling*. The *transcode container type* is specified as `MPEG4` but the result doesn't change if that parameter is deduced from the filename's extension (*.mp4*).

Once the *Sink Writer* is created a new stream is added to it via `AddStream()` and the webcam's *media type* is directly used to specify the output's *media type* as well as in `SetInputMediaType()` call.

A `BeginWriting()` is called to finish the *Sink Writer*'s initialization after which point it is added to the node with a call to `SetObject()`.

A *Tee* is then connecting it's secondary output into the *Sink Writer*'s node and a topology is resolved (successfully) and is presumably ready to go.

Once the topology is queued into a newly created session with the `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_NORESOLUTION` flag (along with the `MFSESSION_SETTOPOLOGY_IMMEDIATE`) the playback and the recording should start - that is my current understanding of how it should work.

However that is where I'm getting a *Media Session Event* via `Invoke()` for the event type `MESessionTopologySet` with an error status code **0x80004002**!

Playing with *Sink Writer*'s attributes (specifying empty/default ones) didn't yield positive results. Moving the topology resolution to happen before I add the writer didn't change anything. Specifying the *primary output stream* for the *Tee* node as going to *EVR* didn't help either.

Disabling MS's *Red-Stone* feature with `EnableFrameServerMode` set to `0` didn't help.

Building and running with **Windows SDK 10.0.10586** on a *Windows 10 Pro* desktop.

---

Below is the log from the **mftrace** for the reference (had to trim a bit to fit into 30K limit):

```
PID, TID    Time (UTC)    TraceMessage
--------- --------------  ------------
...... removed the beginning to save space
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.64241 CMFPlatExportDetours::MFStartup @ Version=0x00020070, dwFlags=0x00000001
...... enumerating hardware and setting up client factories
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.65757 CMFPlatExportDetours::MFStartup @ Version=0x00020070, dwFlags=0x00000000
...... CoCreateInstance calls
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66117 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New MFT @000001B0B3BE3590
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66119 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New source @000001B0B3BEFB80
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66123 CMFMediaSourceDetours::TracePD @000001B0B3BEFB80 Stream 0 (ID 0): selected 1, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66150 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New MFT @000001B0B3BE3590
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66150 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New source @000001B0B3BEFB80
8000,2ED0 21:51:35.66153 CMFMediaSourceDetours::TracePD @000001B0B3BEFB80 Stream 0 (ID 0): selected 1, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33229 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New MFT @000001B0B3BE3590
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33229 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3BE3390 New source @000001B0B3BEFB80
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33233 CMFMediaSourceDetours::TracePD @000001B0B3BEFB80 Stream 0 (ID 0): selected 1, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33272 CMFReadWriteExportDetours::MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL @ URL: 'c:\tmp\rry-raw.mp4', bytestream @0000000000000000, MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING=1;MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE=MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4;MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS=1;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1;MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS=0
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33289 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {48E2ED0F-98C2-4A37-BED5-166312DDD83F} MFReadWrite Class Factory (C:\Windows\System32\mfreadwrite.dll) @000001B0B234EFA0 - traced interfaces: IMFReadWriteClassFactory @000001B0B234EFA0, 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33290 CMFReadWriteClassFactoryDetours::CreateInstanceFromURL @000001B0B234EFA0 URL: 'c:\tmp\rry-raw.mp4', MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING=1;MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE=MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4;MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS=1;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1;MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS=0
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33292 CMFPlatExportDetours::MFCreateFile @ URL: 'c:\tmp\rry-raw.mp4'
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33315 CMFReadWriteClassFactoryDetours::HandleObject @ New sink writer @000001B0B3C01770
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33322 CMFSinkWriterDetours::AddStream @000001B0B3C01770 Stream Index 0x0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33326 CMFSinkWriterDetours::SetInputMediaType @000001B0B3C01770 Stream Index 0x0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33379 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {A22C4FC7-6E91-4E1D-89E9-53B2667B72BA} MF MPEG4 Sink Class Factory (C:\Windows\System32\mfmp4srcsnk.dll) @000001B0B234EFA0 - traced interfaces: 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33423 CMFByteStreamDetours::GetCapabilities @000001B0B3BE0520 Capabilities 0x00000806
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33434 CMFSinkWriterDetours::BeginWriting @000001B0B3C01770 Began writing
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33538 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ New MFT @000001B0B3C24730, VIDEO_ZOOM_RECT=00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3f 00 00 80 3f 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.33539 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {E474E05A-AB65-4F6A-827C-218B1BAAF31F} MF Video Mixer (C:\Windows\System32\evr.dll) @000001B0B3C24730 - traced interfaces: IMFTransform @000001B0B3C24730, 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.38105 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {A0A7A57B-59B2-4919-A694-ADD0A526C373} Tearless Window Presenter (C:\Windows\System32\evr.dll) @000001B0B3C292E8 - traced interfaces: 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.38107 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {98455561-5136-4D28-AB08-4CEE40EA2781} MF Video Presenter (C:\Windows\System32\evr.dll) @000001B0B3C27390 - traced interfaces: 
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.38111 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @000001B0B3C24730 Message type=0x00000002 MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, param=B3C28090
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.39477 CMFActivateDetours::ActivateObject @000001B0B3C00430 New sink @000001B0B3C29950
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.39477 CMFMediaSinkDetours::Attach @000001B0B3C29950 Clock state @000001B0B3C29970
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.40944 CMFTransformDetours::SetInputType @000001B0B3C24730 Succeeded MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.40952 CMFTransformDetours::SetInputType @000001B0B3C2B0F0 Succeeded MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.40986 CMFTransformDetours::SetInputType @000001B0B3C24730 Succeeded MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.40988 CMFTransformDetours::SetOutputType @000001B0B3C2B0F0 Succeeded MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
...... attach clock and rate control
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41105 CTopologyHelpers::Trace @000001B0B3C2A8E0 >>>>>>>>>>>>> input topology
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41106 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 0 @000001B0B3C00430 ID:1F4000000001, 0 inputs, 1 outputs, type 1, MF_TOPONODE_MARKIN_HERE=1;MF_TOPONODE_MARKOUT_HERE=1;MF_TOPONODE_MEDIASTART=0 (0,0);MF_TOPONODE_SOURCE=@000001B0B3BEFB80;MF_TOPONODE_PRESENTATION_DESCRIPTOR=@000001B0B3BF45A0;MF_TOPONODE_STREAM_DESCRIPTOR=@000001B0B3BF4170
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41107 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Source @000001B0B3BEFB80 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFCORE.DLL), MFMEDIASOURCE_CHARACTERISTICS=0x00000005
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41109 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41109 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 1 @000001B0B3C2B030 ID:1F4000000003, 1 inputs, 2 outputs, type 3, MF_TOPONODE_PRIMARYOUTPUT=0
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41109 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Tee @0000000000000000 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} ((null)), (null)
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41111 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C00430 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41112 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ADB0 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41114 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 1, connected to node @000001B0B3C29130 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41115 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 2 @000001B0B3C2ACF0 ID:1F4000000002, 1 inputs, 0 outputs, type 0, MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID=0;MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE=0;MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID={D23E6477-B104-4707-81CB-E1CA19A07016};{B8AA3129-DFC9-423A-8ACD-1D82850A3D1F}=@000001B0B3C27370
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41115 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Sink @000001B0B3C2A048 {D23E6477-B104-4707-81CB-E1CA19A07016} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MF.dll), (null)
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41115 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ADB0 stream 0, MT: >
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41116 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 3 @000001B0B3C2ADB0 ID:1F4000000008, 1 inputs, 1 outputs, type 2, MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID={CF862982-23B0-4E3D-8C76-D03FEF084AF8}
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41116 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ MFT @000001B0B3C2B0F0 {CF862982-23B0-4E3D-8C76-D03FEF084AF8} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFCORE.DLL), MFT_SUPPORT_DYNAMIC_FORMAT_CHANGE=1
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41118 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41120 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ACF0 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41120 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 4 @000001B0B3C29130 ID:1F4000000004, 1 inputs, 0 outputs, type 0, MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID=0;MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE=0
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41120 CMFTopologyNodeDetours::GetGUID @000001B0B3C29130 attribute not found guidKey = MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41121 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ UnknownType @0000000000000000 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} ((null)), (null)
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41121 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 1, MT: >
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41121 CTopologyHelpers::Trace @000001B0B3C2A8E0 MF_TOPOLOGY_RESOLUTION_STATUS = 0
8000,2ED0 21:51:38.41121 CTopologyHelpers::Trace @000001B0B3C2A8E0 >>>>>>>>>>>> queued topology
8000,229C 21:51:38.41144 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 0 @000001B0B3C00430 ID:1F4000000001, 0 inputs, 1 outputs, type 1, MF_TOPONODE_MARKIN_HERE=1;MF_TOPONODE_MARKOUT_HERE=1;MF_TOPONODE_MEDIASTART=0 (0,0);MF_TOPONODE_SOURCE=@000001B0B3BEFB80;MF_TOPONODE_PRESENTATION_DESCRIPTOR=@000001B0B3BF45A0;MF_TOPONODE_STREAM_DESCRIPTOR=@000001B0B3BF4170;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1
8000,229C 21:51:38.41145 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Source @000001B0B3BEFB80 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFCORE.DLL), MFMEDIASOURCE_CHARACTERISTICS=0x00000005
8000,229C 21:51:38.41147 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41147 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 1 @000001B0B3C2B030 ID:1F4000000003, 1 inputs, 2 outputs, type 3, MF_TOPONODE_PRIMARYOUTPUT=0;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1
8000,229C 21:51:38.41148 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Tee @0000000000000000 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} ((null)), (null)
8000,229C 21:51:38.41149 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C00430 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41151 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ADB0 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41152 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 1, connected to node @000001B0B3C29130 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41153 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 2 @000001B0B3C2ACF0 ID:1F4000000002, 1 inputs, 0 outputs, type 0, MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID=0;MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE=0;MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID={D23E6477-B104-4707-81CB-E1CA19A07016};{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1;{B8AA3129-DFC9-423A-8ACD-1D82850A3D1F}=@000001B0B3C27370
8000,229C 21:51:38.41153 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ Sink @000001B0B3C2A048 {D23E6477-B104-4707-81CB-E1CA19A07016} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MF.dll), (null)
8000,229C 21:51:38.41153 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ADB0 stream 0, MT: >
8000,229C 21:51:38.41154 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 3 @000001B0B3C2ADB0 ID:1F4000000008, 1 inputs, 1 outputs, type 2, MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID={CF862982-23B0-4E3D-8C76-D03FEF084AF8};{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1
8000,229C 21:51:38.41155 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ MFT @000001B0B3C2B0F0 {CF862982-23B0-4E3D-8C76-D03FEF084AF8} (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFCORE.DLL), MFT_SUPPORT_DYNAMIC_FORMAT_CHANGE=1;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1
8000,229C 21:51:38.41156 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41158 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Output stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2ACF0 stream 0, MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=1374389534960 (320,240);MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=36864000;MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING=3;MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE=640;MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING=6;MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=FORMAT_VIDEOINFO2;MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1;MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=153600;MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES=2;MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX=128849018881 (30,1);MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_YUY2
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CTopologyHelpers::TraceNode @ Node 4 @000001B0B3C29130 ID:1F4000000004, 1 inputs, 0 outputs, type 0, MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID=0;MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE=0;{9C27891A-ED7A-40E1-88E8-B22727A024EE}=1
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CMFTopologyNodeDetours::GetGUID @000001B0B3C29130 attribute not found guidKey = MF_TOPONODE_TRANSFORM_OBJECTID
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CTopologyHelpers::TraceObject @ UnknownType @0000000000000000 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} ((null)), (null)
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CTopologyHelpers::TraceStream @ Input stream 0, connected to node @000001B0B3C2B030 stream 1, MT: >
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CTopologyHelpers::Trace @000001B0B3C2A8E0 MF_TOPOLOGY_RESOLUTION_STATUS = 0
8000,229C 21:51:38.41159 CTopologyHelpers::Trace @000001B0B3C2A8E0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sink Writer* is not a valid object to be specified for the *Output Node*. The only two valid objects for that are `IMFStreamSink` and `IMFActivate`.

Once the `IMFStreamSink` was properly created and configured everything else started working like a charm.

Steps to create the `IMFStreamSink` to be used in the node's `SetObject()` call:

1. Create `IMFByteStream` (for instance via `MFCreateFile()`)
2. Create `IMFMediaSink` based on that `IMFByteStream` and set it up (described in MSDN)
3. Using `GetStreamSinkById()` get the `IMFStreamSink` object - that is the one to use in the node's `SetObject()` call!